# Kubernetes Pod will restart after deleting

Tags: kubernetes

I created a pod that I want to delete but it does not seem te work.

I did all ready tried a lot of different things.

I do not have deployments or replica sets, as a lot of people suggest to delete those.

When i type:
`kubectl get all`
Only the pod and the service is visible, both of which will return upon deleting them.

When i type:

`kubectl delete pods <pod-name> --grace-period=0 --force`

The pod will come back again.

Is there something else I can do?

Comment: Do you have some other operator deployed that could recreate the pods and services?

Comment: What pod is it?

Comment: are you deploying your pods using `helm` ?

Comment: I have no other operator deployed. I’m not deploying the pods using helm.

Comment: Hello, please tell how exactly have you created this `Pod`. Was it with `$ kubectl create`, was it `YAML` definiton? Was it through some kind of dashboard?

Answer (score 2):

If pod not part of the deployment, rs, sts, ds, then it must be part of the static pod. Static pod name combines with node (i.e staticpod-node01). By default location of the static path is /etc/Kubernetes/manifest/.
Doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/static-pod/

Comment: I have no /etc/kubernetes/manifest folder I believe.

Comment: What pod name? Is pod name combine with Node name where the pod is running?

Comment: The name is tfjob-test-chief-0, i dont believe its a combination of the node name

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it was some sort of invisible job that started the pod.
It was not showing when entering `kubectl get jobs`

So when finding this job and deleting it the pod disappeared!